# Does the 200-points cap affect the user page?

Tags: discussion

In [[ users ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=3&tab=reputation&filter=week) page, it is possible to list users as per reputation earned per week.

Does the 200 points cap per day for a user affect weekly points earned as displayed in this page?

Comment: @yellowantphil you mean logically why wouldn't it. Otherwise there is timing, cacheing, bugs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. Without winning bounties or having your answers accepted, you can't earn more than 1400 reputation per week.